# When I change the text color of UITextField inside a UITableView, the color has applied to another UITextfield when I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, swift5

I really don't understand why this happen. I'm changing the text color of a UITextField that is inside a UITableView if the text has changed but when I scroll down or up the tableView other UITextFields change the text color.
How can solve this problem?

Here is my code and some screenshot of the problem:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "ApcGenericCell"
private let portIdentifier = "ApcPortCell"
private let addressIdentifier = "ApcAddressCell"

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tableView: UITableView!

    private var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var newBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var apc = [Apc]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // configure the table view for the left menu
        configureTableView()
    }

    private func configureTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 60

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ApcGeneric", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ApcPortAt", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: portIdentifier)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ApcIpAddress", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: addressIdentifier)
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.height / 8).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: view.frame.width / 8).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -(view.frame.width / 8)).isActive = true
        bottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -(view.frame.height / 8))
        bottomConstraint.isActive = true

        tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

        // register for notifications when the keyboard appears and disappears:
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(note:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(note:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedMessage), name: Notification.Name("ReceivedMessage"), object: nil)

        apc = ApcSection.emptySection()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func receivedMessage() {
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        ApcSection.fetchData(map: self.apcConfig, { (apcResult) in
          self.apc = apcResult

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
       })
      }
    }

    // Handle keyboard frame changes here.
    // Use the CGRect stored in the notification to determine what part of the screen the keyboard will cover.
    // Adjust our table view's bottomAnchor so that the table view content avoids the part of the screen covered by the keyboard
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
        // read the CGRect from the notification (if any)
        if let newFrame = (note.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if bottomConstraint.isActive {
                bottomConstraint.isActive = false
                newBottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -newFrame.height)
                newBottomConstraint.isActive = true
                tableView.updateConstraints()
            }
        }
    }

    // User dismiss the keyboard
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(note: NSNotification) {
        newBottomConstraint.isActive = false
        bottomConstraint.isActive = true
        tableView.updateConstraints()
    }

    @objc func textHasChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

        if let index = indexPath?.row {

            if let _ = apc[index] {
                // change textColor if the value has been changed
              if sender.text != apc[index]!) {
                    sender.textColor = .systemRed
                } else {
                    sender.textColor = .myBlue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return apc.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: portIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ApcPortAt
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 9 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: addressIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ApcIpAddress
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ApcGeneric
            cell.value.text = apc[indexPath.row]
            cell.value.delegate = self
            cell.value.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textHasChanged(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

[Normal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6F0V.jpg)

[Editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kpLF.jpg)

[Scroll down after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r4VA.jpg)

[Return to the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwM8V.jpg)

Comment: I think the key thing to remember here is, you cells aren't `static`, the `UITableView` will re-use the same instance if `UITableViewCell` over and over again, which is why you have `dequeueReusableCell`.  The `UITableView` is make decisions about when it needs to create a new cell or reuse one it has cached.  So, the thing to remember is, when you dequeue a cell, you need to reset it's state to meet the requirements of the data it is representing

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possible solutions
1. Apply the changes in cellForRowAt of UITableViewDataSource delegate.
2. Subclass UITableViewCell and override prepareForReuse() which within it you can make your updates. And don't forget to register the cell subclass with your table view.
I consider solution #1 much easier

Comment: May I ask you another question? In the same situation how can I disable the edit for all textFields inside the cells? I tried with: ```tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false ``` to disable the interaction on all the tableView but it doesn't work until I refresh the table.

Comment: You can retrieve visible cells and retrieve UITextField components then apply your changes.
Don't forget to conform to UITableViewDelegate and override tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)

Answer (score 2):

[image: UITablView reusable]
In UITableView dequeueReusableCell- Each UITableViewCell will be reused several times with different data(image).
In your case, When you scrolled, cell at IndexPath(row: x, section: 0) was reused by another cell that is displaying at the top. Ex: cell with red text -> this cell x have red text, because you did not reset the text color to it
Solution:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ApcGeneric
    cell.value.text = apc[indexPath.row]
    if index == selectedIndex { // condition to red text
        cell.value.textColor = .systemRed
    } else {
        cell.value.textColor = .myBlue
    }
    cell.value.delegate = self
    cell.value.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textHasChanged(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
```